# how do we forecast TS data with factors in r

Tags: r, time-series, multi-level

I am looking for straight or correct way of forcasting a TS data with 3 different sublevel for quartely sales quantity.Below is sample case data, can anyone advice on this. Thank you.

```
Region<-rep(c("US","UK"),6)
SalesOffice<-rep(c("office1","office2","office3","office4"),3)
Product <-rep(c("items1","items2","items3", "items4", "items5","items6"),2) 
Quantity <-c(12,23,34,32,33,23,24,41,23,22,21,14)
salesdata<-data.frame(Region,SalesOffice,Product,Quantity)
salesdata.ts<-ts(salesdata,frequency = 4,start = c(2013,2))
```

Comment: Your last line suggests each row corresponds to a different quarter. But the labels suggest otherwise. Please clarify

Comment: Rob, Label remains same. May be you can omit last line and suggest with your added or suggested line to forecast TS model, say Holtwinter! Thank you.